# How to run docker-compose with custom file name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this file: `docker-compose.test.yml`

But when I try to run `docker-compose`, this happens:

```sh
$ docker-compose up
ERROR:
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

**Is there some option to specify which file to use?**

Comment: This is where the `--file` option is described in the Docker Compose CLI [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)

Comment: Why downvote? And this is not a ducplicate at least for the question referred as a duplicate.

Comment: @ValentineShi The duplicate is not right, asking for a nice filename and how to use a filename as a parameter are different things. Anyway, the question itself is too easy: you can just read it in the official docs in a minute. Not enough research effort. Most of us would still quickly check Stack Exchange before entering the long docs, therefore the upvotes of the answer. It does not meet the rules to ask a too easy question.

Comment: @ValentineShi I took the advice from the answer here, although I have done this many times before. You want to make sure you have it right. As to the rules, it is said that you must do a quick research before you ask. And also, if you ask for just this one parameter, you could ask one question for each parameter. Moreover, all of the docker questions do not belong to StackOverflow but to SuperUser or Unix&Linux since they do not deal with coding, but with parameters and commands.

Comment: @ValentineShi "Me alone" does not put it right, if this is about the rules. It is not even me who has this opinion. If it were for me, I would not even have different StackExchanges, but just chosen forced tags. This is a meta discussion and off-topic here. Two new meta questions about this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406267/does-this-question-live-a-not-justified-life-as-an-alleged-duplicate and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406268/is-an-easy-docker-question-about-a-command-parameter-and-which-does-not-have-any.

Comment: @ValentineShi You won, it is on-topic. Less important: surprisingly, marking it as a duplicate here is right since it is only about the answers - even if that other answer belongs to a closed question. Then the question and answer also get my upvote now, at least the -1 at the time of writing is not logical if the answer is obviously used by many.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use `-f` option to specify the file name.

Example:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up
```

Comment: Note that any options for the `up` command comes after it.

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/#use--f-to-specify-name-and-path-of-one-or-more-compose-files